# Capture modifier keys (control/ctrl, shift, alt) on data feature click events in google maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, click, mouseevent, modifier-key

I have a project using the Google Maps JS API and I'm loading data onto it using the `loadGeoJSON` method. I also add a click listener to the map's data object.

In that click listener handler, I extract the mouseEvent which tells me the x,y that the user clicked as well as if they were holding down shift/alt/ctrl. Something changed recently though because I can't detect shift/alt/ctrl any more. They are always false.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This fiddle should show more clearly what I'm talking about, just click on one of the 'google' letters.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z4fpbf8/1/)

Comment: There was a [new release of the Javascript API](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/JKGnj4hTiFA) that was released earlier this week. Your fiddle is loading 3.33 (experimental version). As a temporary workaround, if you put `"&v=3.31"` (frozen version) in the URL, the events should be captured again.

Comment: I believe it's worth filing a bug in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188851&template=789203